# Can't see User fields as options for a context filter

Tags: 7, views

I was following [this video](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/772) to add a contextual filter so the page I'm creating would display content created by the logged-in user only.

However, when I scroll down the list of contextual filters, I don't see the `User:` options. How can I see them? Am I missing some module or option? My Drupal 7 setup is almost all by default.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you're watching is out of date (I watched it too); it was created when Views was in beta/RC and things have changed a bit since then.

You just need to add the user as a Relationship under the "Advanced" options...then you'll get the user filters as you'd expect.